# Get a higher average population of cities that fall into a certain country name

Tags: python, sql, pandasql

I have a case problem like this (pandasql):

> Find cities in the United States (uscity) that meet all of the
> following conditions:
>
> - has the name 'city' which is not the same as 'state_name', and also
> - has a population above the average population of the cities in 'county_name' Miami-Dade, and also
> - consists of two or more words (example: Los Angeles, New York)
>
> The expected output is only the 'city' column, no need for other
> columns
>
> Do only 1x query, don't do more than 1 query

```
query = """
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM uscity 
WHERE city != state_name
AND avg(population) > country_name = 'Miami-Dade'
AND city like '% %'
"""

sql_run(query)
```

However, after I run the code, I can't get the output.

Comment: What is `AND avg(population) > country_name = 'Miami-Dade'` supposed to do?

Comment: How to decide if it's one word or more? Is 'Miami-Dade' one word or two?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error message ?

Also the avg(population) > country_name = 'Miami-Dade' is incorrect.

You need a city which has a population above the average population of the cities in 'county_name' Miami-Dade. So population > avg(select population from uscity where country_name = 'Miami-Dade')

```csharp
query = """
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM uscity 
WHERE city != state_name
AND population > avg(select population from uscity where country_name = 'Miami-Dade')
AND city like '% %'
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly changed the answer you wrote

Maybe this will help because I've tried it and it works

```
query = """
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM uscity 
WHERE population > (SELECT avg(population) 
                    FROM uscity 
                    WHERE county_name = 'Miami-Dade')
AND city != state_name
AND city like '% %'
"""
sql_run(query)
```